# Межсайтовая авторизация

Tags: поддомены, php, клиент-сервер, сервер, javascript

Разрабатываю сайт где разделы размещении на поддоменах. 
Например politic.site.ru, sport.site.ru.

Планирую позже подключить еще и совсем другой домен (site2.ru). Проблема в том, что нужно чтобы пользователь авторизировавшись на сайте/разделе (любом) автоматически вошел и на других разделах (поддоменах, и доменах).

Сессия на поддомены не передается... cookies тоже.

Сейчас решил проблему как написано тут: http://habrahabr.ru/post/80900/

Все работает но етот метод не особо красивый, плюс лишняя перезагрузка страницы при входе если пользователь уже вошел.

Есть какой-то другой, более красивый способ сделать это и без перезагрузок (было бы идеально с помощью серверной части сайта без применения js)

Comment: > автоматически вошел и на других разделах (поддоменах

достаточно задавать куки/сессию на `.site.ru` (внимание на точку cпереди)

> и доменах

распылить куки/сессию на два домена не получится никак.

Comment: @Fike но авторизовать можно, например куку можно протащить через js запрос.